# Finding the correspondences between the camera image and the projected image

Tags: image-processing

I am projecting an image via projector and capturing it via camera.
   The projection is small part of the captured image.
   How could I establish correspondence between the original and the captured image.

Please let me know if anything remains unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would just project a small dot with nothing else, which would be easy to spot in the captured image. Then I would just move the dot all over the places then you would get the corresponding map on the entire projected image.